# Selenium XPATH preceding-sibling not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class=”ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none” role=”presentation”
  <span ref=”eMENU” class=”ag-header-icon ag-header-cell-menu-button” aria-hidden=”true” style=”transition:opacity 0.2s;>
    <span class=”ag-icon ag-icon-menu”></span>
  </span>
  <div ref=”eLabel” class=”ag-header-cell-label” role=”presentation”>
    <span ref=”eText” class=”ag-header-cell-text role=”columnheader”> Product</span>
```

I need to click on the `ag-icon ag-icon menu` in my application for the column Product.
I have written the below xpath to do the same. But there are more than 1 element matching the xpath given in sibling and that's why I have hard coded the occurrence as [1]. Is there a way to get click on the `ag-icon ag-icon menu` without using the reference?

```
WebElement pipeline = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Product']"));
WebElement parent = pipeline.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
WebElement sibling = parent.findElement(By.xpath("(//preceding-sibling::span[@class='g-header-icon ag-header-cell-menu-button']/span)[1]"));
sibling.click();
```

Comment: What u want to select

Comment: The first class is `ag-header-icon`, not `g-header-icon`. You are missing the `a`.

Comment: It is still unclear which element you want to click.

Comment: The path `//preceding-sibling::span` is pretty meaningless - it selects every span in the document that is the preceding sibling of something. I suspect the leading "//" was added as magic fairy dust, and should be left off.

Comment: you need to provide some of the matching nodes to get good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Option 1
String xpath = "//div[div/span[@role='columnheader' and text()='Product']" + 
"//span[contains(@class, 'ag-icon-menu')]"

driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();


// Option 2
String xpath = "//div[div/span[@role='columnheader' and text()='Product']"
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))
      .findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ag-icon-menu"))
      .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below xpath and it will work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'ag-icon') and contains(@class,'ag-icon-menu')]")).click();
```

When the class attribute has multiple unique values, then we can use "AND" condition